# NameError: name 'self' is not defined - module import

Tags: python

EDIT: here is the current issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "figure.py", line 32, in <module> import Python2 
File "C:\scripts\python2.py", line 12, in <module> shp = shape.Python1(self.size, self.length, self.breadth,self.height) 
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

---

Though this question has been asked many times it hasn't solved my issue.

I have two python files `python1.py` and `python2.py`

In `python1.py`:

```
def add(self,a):
    .....

def sub(self,b):
    ....
```

In `python2.py`:

```
import python1

def square (self,c):
    python1.add(a)
```

When I try to run this, in `python2.py` I get `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'add'`. what should I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please post code that actually reproduces the error when run, as well as the complete stack trace of the error.

Answer (score 1):

Given that `add` takes two arguments (`self` and `a`), I'm assuming that it is contained within a class. You can either do this:

```
from python1 import YourClass

YourClass().add(a)
```

or this:

```
import python1
python1.YourClass().add(a)
```

**In response to the comments:**
`self` does not need to be included in the actuall *call* of a method or class initialization. Here is how you should call it:

```
python1.shape(w, x, y, z) #as opposed to python1.shape(self.w, self.x, self.y, self.z)
```

and then they will be assigned as instance variables (`self` variables) in the class' `__init__` function.

Comment: Yes it is contained in class and I give few arguments to a class. no do I have to use yourclass(args).add(a)  or    just yourclass().add(a)

Comment: well you have to replace `YourClass` with the actual name of the class. Also, you do have to import the class to use functions within it. The first argument `self` in a method is the instance of the class that the function is being called from.

Comment: yaa I am using the same.But for the class shape which I am using, it has 4arguments. do I have to use shape(w,x,y,z).add(a) or shape().add(a).

Comment: Also I tried to do  shp = python1.shape(w,x,y,z) outside the class of python2 and used shp.add(a)

Comment: yes `shp = python1.shape(w,x,y,z)` will work as long as you have it properly imported, and then to call the `add` method you use `shp.add(a)`.

Comment: I used import python1

Comment: but for the arguments in shp = python1.shape(w,x,y,z) I had to use self.w,self.x,self.y,self.z and it gives me an error : self not defined

Comment: you'll have to post the relevant code in your question. (meaning the code that raises the error.)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "figure.py", line 32, in <module>
    import Python2
  File "C:\scripts\python2.py", line 12, in <module>
    shp = shape.Python1(self.size, self.length, self.breadth,self.height)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: shp = shape.Python1(self.size, self.length, self.breadth,self.height)
def square(self,sides):
        shp.add(a+self.b)